# Upload de foto no formulário java

Tags: java, primefaces

Preciso fazer com que meu formulário envie e guarde uma foto no banco de dados e mostre posteriormente, como devo fazer ?

Declaro que tipo de variavel na entidade Cliente? String ou byte ?

Sei que o primefaces tem um componente mas não sei como fazer. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Se está usando primefaces, provavelmente o melhor caminho é usar o file upload mesmo. Acredito que o exemplo da documentação seja o suficiente para começar a usar.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml

Você basicamente precisa de um formulário com o componente do file upload.

O objeto que será retornado para o seu ManagedBean será do tipo [UploadFile](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile.html) e através dele você pode pegar os bytes, nome do arquivo entre outras coisas por exemplo:

```
@ManagedBean
public class FileUploadView {

    private UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void upload() {
        if(file != null) {
             System.out.println("Nome do arquivo: " + file.getFileName());
             file.getContents(); //array de bytes
             files.getInputStream();//input stream do arquivo
        }
    }
}
```

Uma vez que você tenha este `file` você precisa decidir como vai armazenar esta imagem. Eu vejo duas possíveis soluções:

**1 - Armazenar os bytes da imagem no banco:**

A primeira é salvar a imagem em bytes mesmo em uma coluna no banco, neste caso vai depender do banco que estiver usando, o mysql possui o tipo BLOB por exemplo.
Neste caso sua entidade Cliente teria um campo do tipo array de bytes `private byte[] foto;`. Se estiver usando JPA é recomedável que use a anotação `@Lob`.

**2 - Salvar o arquivo em uma pasta:**

A outra opção seria salvar esta imagem em uma pasta (que pode estar no servidor mesmo ou em um local na rede acessível) e salvar no banco somente o caminho necessário para recuperar esta imagem.
Neste caso sua variável seria somente uma string com o caminho `private String foto`.

A segunda opção costuma ser melhor devido a não armazenar diretamente no banco arquivo que podem ser grandes aumentando bastante o tamanho da tabela desnecessariamente.